# time function always gives me 0.0 output

Tags: python, tkinter, time

Im trying to make a CPS counter, and when I reach 100 clicks, its supposed to print "test" and also print the time it took to get to 100 clicks. But it always gives 0.0 as the time output.

```
import tkinter
import time

counter = tkinter.Tk()

clicks = 0

def addClick():
    global clicks
    clicks = clicks + 1
    lbl.configure(text=clicks)

    start = time.time()
    if clicks == 100:
        print("test")
        end = time.time()
        print(start - end)

lbl = tkinter.Label(counter, text = clicks)
lbl.pack()

btn = tkinter.Button(counter, text="Click here", command=addClick)
btn.pack()


counter.mainloop()
```

Comment: You set `start` every time you call `addClick`, just before your if condition. You should set `start` outside the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
... 
start = time.time()
if clicks == 100:
    print("test")
    end = time.time()
    print(start - end)
```

You keep restarting `start` after every click. A possible solution would be to start it only after the first click. This will require `start` to be a global variable as well.

Also note that you should do `end - start`, not `start - end`.

```
clicks = 0
start = None
...
global clicks
global start
...

if clicks == 1:
    # instantiating 'start' only if it was the first click
    start = time.time()
elif clicks == 100:
    print("test")
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)
```

However, using global variables is quite a code-smell and an anti-pattern, and we already have 2 of them in such a tiny program.

You can try to wrap them in a data-structure such as a `dict`:

```
import tkinter
import time

counter = tkinter.Tk()

data = {'clicks': 0, 'start': None}

def addClick():
    data['clicks'] += 1
    lbl.configure(text=data['clicks'])

    if data['clicks'] == 1:
        # instantiating 'start' only if it was the first click
        data['start'] = time.time()
    elif data['clicks'] == 100:
        print("test")
        end = time.time()
        print(end - data['start'])

lbl = tkinter.Label(counter, text=data['clicks'])
lbl.pack()

btn = tkinter.Button(counter, text="Click here", command=addClick)
btn.pack()

counter.mainloop()
```

Another, real-world fitting solution would be to wrap the entire tkinter app in a class, that can keep track of its own state.